# list as columns in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list for example:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

and I want to convert it into a matrix that looks like so:

```
mat = [ 1  1  1 
        2  2  2
        3  3  3
        4  4  4
        5  5  5 ]
```

so each column in the matrix is the list.

is there an easy way doing so with numpy or just regular python?

thank you

Comment: How would you know the number of columns?

Comment: is no. of columns is always 3??

Comment: `y = [[v for i in range(columns)] for v in x]`, where `columns` is the number of columns, which is 3 in your case. Not a `numpy` solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to repeat i.e

```
n = 3 # No of repetition 
np.repeat(np.array(x),n).reshape(-1,n) 

array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

without any modules

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n = 3
b = [[x] * n for x in a]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's use np.tile:

```
 import numpy as np
 arr = np.array(x)
 np.tile(arr,3).reshape(5,3, order='F')
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another array option:

```
In [248]: np.stack([a]*3,axis=1)
Out[248]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [3, 3, 3],
       [4, 4, 4],
       [5, 5, 5]])
```

You need to be careful with list replication:

```
In [250]: b=[a]*3
In [251]: b[0][0]=30
In [252]: b
Out[252]: [[30, 2, 3, 4, 5], [30, 2, 3, 4, 5], [30, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
# a is also changed
```

It replicates the pointer, not the values.  The array stack makes a copy.

`np.array` will join those lists along a new first axis.  `stack` does something similar (but using `np.concatenate`), and allows us to join them on a new 2nd axis.

```
In [255]: np.array(b)
Out[255]: 
array([[30,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [30,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [30,  2,  3,  4,  5]])
```